# how to save data from a fetch request in a global array?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch an array of objects from the Star Wars API and store it in a global array to use array methods on it. of course, since sending a request is a side effect, when I use the push method to push the data into a variable which is an array, the data is pushed into the array, but the length of the array is 0 and I can't use any array methods on it. I was wondering what is the best way to save data in a global variable when using fetch and if you can elaborate a bit on what causes this behavior. Thanks in advance

first I tried the following code, the peopleArray is populated with an array of 10 objects but the length is 0

```
let peopleArray = [];

function fetchCountries(){
    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
    .then(res => res.json()
    .then(data => peopleArray.push(data.results)))
    
}
fetchCountries()
console.log(peopleArray);
```

Then i tried this approach:

```
let peopleArray = [];

async function fetchPeople(){
    const response = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people');
    const data = await response.json()
    return data.results
}

fetchPeople().then(data => peopleArray.push(...data))

console.log(peopleArray.length); // is zero
```

can anyone points where in my code i'm making a mistake?

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous, so you're going to have to wait for it to finish, which means you're either going to have to "literally" do that using `await`, or put all the code that has to happen after you fill your array, inside the final `then` handler.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/328193)